# Use `interp1` as a lookup function

Tags: matlab

I am using `interp1` to look up values from a vector `calculate_a1` and use them in `ode45`.

I have 3 different function files to achieve this. `system1` where my equations are defined, `system1solver` which solves the function and `calculate_a1` which defines the parameter a1.

`system1solver` is defined as follows:

```
tStep = linspace(0,25,26); 
alpha = calculate_a1();

%% Solver
sol = ode45(@(t,x)system1(t,x,tStep,alpha),tStep,IC);
```

and the term`a1` in `system1` is as follows:

```
a1 = interp1(tStep,alpha,t)
```

My issue is that at each interpolation `interp1` uses a value of `calculate_a1`. This means that whilst I want to change `a1` after every 25 time points, it changes after every 25 iterations of `interp1`. Obviously, this is causing my model to be hugely wrong! Is there a way I can use `interp1` as a look up function without actually interpolating?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to create a temporary vector which is interpolated one time, in the beginning, and then just refer back to that vector all the time instead of recalculating the entire thing every time.

Answer (score 0):

I thinhk your problem is that you use as lookup value the number of the iterration insted of the number of the time point.

Here is a link in the Matlab site showing how intepr1 works

[interp1 1-D data interpolation (table lookup)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html)

> vq = interp1(x,v,xq) returns interpolated values of a 1-D function at
> specific query points using linear interpolation. Vector x contains
> the sample points, and v contains the corresponding values, v(x).
> Vector xq contains the coordinates of the query points.
>
> If you have multiple sets of data that are sampled at the same point
> coordinates, then you can pass v as an array. Each column of array v
> contains a different set of 1-D sample values.

I hope i was helpfull

Comment: So I need to define `xq`? What would I need to define this as?

Comment: The xq must be the value to be found in the x so the function return the equivalent v.

Comment: So in this case it would just be a vector containing the numbers 1:26, because there are 26 elements in my tStep vector?

Comment: Look sum examples:
`interp1(1:100,100:-1:1,5)
ans = 96
interp1(1:100,100:-1:1,1)
ans =100
interp1(1:100,100:-1:1,1.5)
ans = 99.5`

In the file you define the equations matlab can evaluate values for every time. Thats the why yoy have to use an `interp1` command. The numerical integration in the `ode45` code is based in the Runge–Kutta methods that avaluate the values of the equations with very smal time steps.

So the t in your code must be the time of numerical intertion of the ode45 code
The x must be the points that you difine the alpha
The v must the alphas that corresponds the time points